# How to redirect a file within a folder from http to its https counterpart?

Tags: ruby, apache, .htaccess, https, ubuntu-12.04

I have a website (built in ruby with .erb extensions) with mixed content (like a Wistia video) and so want to have that URL as http://domain.com.

However, when users click on "register," I want to direct them to an EV SSL-encrypted https://subdomain.domain.com/register folder.

Both of the above URLs work just fine, and the https URL displays the green EV SSL properly.

BUT, if in the low-probability event a user were to type "http://*/register" into his browser's address bar, that goes to the same /register page and allows him to register on that non-encrypted page. I really do not want that to happen.

I want to redirect anyone who tries to access the /register file via http to only the EV SSL-encrypted one, that is: https://*/register

sorry for using * wildcard, but I can only post 2 links.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 OS on an apache2 server and generally modify via ssh on my Mac's Terminal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying so quickly, Anu. That may have worked, but Rackspace support used a 301 redirect in a .conf file, and it definitely worked:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf:5
==================================
redirect 301 /register https://subdomain.domain.com/register
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^register(/.*)?$ https://subdomain.domain.com/register$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```